# Incoming mail rejected with "Invalid HELO name"

Tags: smtp, exim

I'm unable to receive important emails from someone, with this error in my exim log:

```
2015-01-21 11:30:16 H=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]:50143
  X=TLSv1:AES256-SHA:256 rejected MAIL <xxx@xxx.xxx>: Access denied -
  Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)
```

Is there anything I can do on my end to let the mail come through, even though their server is miss-configured?

This is just to block spam right? I don't really have a spam problem and don't mind if it increases a bit.

I'm running CentOS/WHM 11.x on CentOS 5.11.

Comment: Don't do this. Tell the other end that their mail server is misconfigured. If they don't want to fix it, then they obviously don't want you to receive their mail.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have told them, but I suspect they may be too incompetent to fix it.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by disabling the  following configuration in WHM:

> Service Configuration > Exim Configuration Manager > Require RFC-compliant HELO

Not sure if that was the best solution, but it worked.

Comment: Likely this is the point-and-click'y way of disabling the entire check that BillThor told you to modify in his answer.

Comment: @ToddLyons sure. In my experience editing files that are managed by cPanel is dangerous. Sometimes they're overwritten, other times they cause a conflict and bring the server down requiring a full restore. Since cPanel auto-applies patches from a cron job to fight security vulnerabilities, it's a ticking time bomb. I've seen problems only occur after a service is restarted for example. It's always best to use the GUI when possible with cPanel, I used Bill's answer to help find what I actually ended up doing.

Comment: Apologies if it sounded like I disapproved or otherwise disagreed with the answer. It is a perfectly valid solution, especially when the configuration is so tightly controlled by the external application.

Answer (score 3):

There should a white list file you can add their IP address to. Look in the Exim configuration file for the the `Invalid HELO name` message.  There should be lookup there.  This will be the file you need to add the address to.

Check your logs to see which servers you are blocking.  Unfortunately, you are likely blocking banks, airlines, and governments among others.  All organizations that should be capable of getting something this simple right.